# Recommend german TV series

Tags: resource

I am interested in german TV series to practice my German this way (I believe, I have B1 or maybe A2/B1 level). And I am really interested in native German series, not dubbed american ones, and I have no idea about them. I would appreciate if somebody would recommend me the ones (titles/examples of specific series) which are:

- originally in German language, preferably not too much local dialects
- Not documentary or learning ones
- Not too much soap opera style
- relatively popular/well-known in Germany so that I would be able to find subs for them

Comment: Either you don't practice German that way, or every series is equally suited for your needs. What you end up looking is just a matter of taste, or more specific, of a lack thereof.

Comment: Star Trek has very good and understable German syncron. It is also very, very long.

Comment: You shouldn't rule out dubs because the German they use in dubs is natural. It's not like the cheap overdubs you may be used to.

Answer (score 2):

*Lindenstraße* is a classic and you should not have  a problem finding German language subs (and perhaps some other languages) for it. It depicts the everyday life of neighbors, often focusing on social problem or curent topics. Because of the topics and the setting I would think that it is quite useful for German learners.

Another famous long running series is *Gute Zeiten Schleche Zeiten (GZSZ)*, but IMO more soapy than "Lindenstraße" and aimed at a younger audience.

Answer (score 1):

"Dark" (on Netflix) was really good. A little like "Stranger Things". It's a German series so spoken in German and you can get either German or English subtitles.